# initalize database on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I've looked at many tutorials and guides online but I can't get my application to initialize just one insert statement on startup from data.sql .

I created an @Entity, and an @Repository, which I can access when the application is running and add things to it. When attempting to add a data.sql file with a single statement to load on startup, it doesn't load into the table.

Here is my properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=uname
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql
```

Here is my data.sql file:

```
INSERT INTO name VALUES('bob','smith');
```

As I said, the repository and entity seem to start up fine blank and allow me to add to them, so I think they are set up fine. What should I be doing instead of the above for load simple initial data?

Comment: So where did you put the data.sql file?

Comment: It's called database migration. As per I know two libraries provide this support, Flyway & Liquibase. Use it as per your fa. I prefer Flyway because it follow human readable format where as liquibase is in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the data.sql file under the **src/main/resources** folder.

> INSERT INTO name VALUES('bob','smith');

Entity class has to be the field of **@Id**. annotation
example:

```
@Entity
public class Name {

    @Id
    private String name;

    private String surname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a dependency called Flyway, it takes care of running scripts on automatically on application start up.

Add below properties in application.properties file of project

spring.flyway.enabled=true

spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/sql

where spring.flyway.locations refers to the location of DB script files(Above example specifies to look for files under folder src/main/resources/db/sql/).

For additional more details, Please refer below link:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: @GameDroids Updated as per your comments.